# Given $x \wedge y=\mathbf{F}$, how to simplify $x \wedge \lnot y$?

Tags: problem-solving, boolean-algebra

Given that the boolean expression $x \wedge y=\mathbf{F}$, how to simplify $x \wedge \lnot y$?

Is the above question equivalent to the following question?

Find z so that $\lnot(x \wedge y)\rightarrow \left [ (x \wedge \lnot y) \Leftrightarrow z \right ]$ is a tautology.

If the two are equivalent, can you solve the problem from the two perspectives if possible?

I want **formal ways which can handle two or even ten variables** because this is the simplified version of my real question. I'm writing a program that has complicate logic.

```
    if (!a && b && d)
    {
        //do action a
    }
    else if (!a && b && !d)
    {
        //do action b
    }
    else if (!b && c || a && c)
    {
        //do action c
    }
    else if(a && !c || !b && !c)
    {
        //do action d
    }
    else
    {//do action e  }
```

Given `!a && b && d` is false, can we simplify `!a && b && !d`?

Given `!a && b && d`=`!a && b && !d`=false, can we simplify `!b && c || a && c`?

Given `!a && b && d`=`!a && b && !d`=`!b && c || a && c`=false, can we simplify `a && !c || !b && !c`?

I try to simplify the if condition in order to lower the CPU usage.

Comment: have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_maps#Don.27t_cares

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we know that $x\wedge y$ is false, then $x$ and $y$ are not both true. Thus, $x\wedge\neg y$ is true if and only if [fill in the blank with one of $x,y$] is true.  The filled-in blank is the desired $z$ / "simplified" version of $x\wedge\neg y$.

**Added**: Given that $\neg a\wedge b\wedge d$ is false, then $$\begin{align}\neg a\wedge b\wedge\neg d &= (\neg a\wedge b\wedge\neg d)\vee F\\ &= (\neg a\wedge b\wedge\neg d)\vee(\neg a\wedge b\wedge d)\\ &= (\neg a\wedge b)\wedge(d\vee\neg d)\\ &= (\neg a\wedge b)\wedge T\\ &=\neg a\wedge b.\end{align}$$

Given that $\neg a\wedge b\wedge d$ and $\neg a\wedge b\wedge\neg d$ are false (that is, that $\neg a\wedge b$ is false), then we know $$T=\neg(\neg a\wedge b)=a\vee\neg b,$$ so $$\begin{align}(\neg b\wedge c)\vee(a\wedge c) &= (a\wedge c)\vee(\neg b\wedge c)\\ &= (a\vee\neg b)\wedge c\\ &= T\wedge c\\ &= c.\end{align}$$

Given that $\neg a\wedge b\wedge d$ and $\neg a\wedge b\wedge\neg d$ and $(\neg b\wedge c)\vee(a\wedge c)$ are false (that is, that $a\vee\neg b$ is true and $c$ is false), then $$\begin{align}(\neg b\wedge\neg c)\vee(a\wedge\neg c) &= (a\wedge\neg c)\vee(\neg b\wedge\neg c)\\ &= (a\wedge T)\vee(\neg b\wedge T)\\ &= a\wedge\neg b\\ &= T.\end{align}$$

Comment: Yes, so I'm asking how to find z.

Comment: Oops! My answer had an error. Now fixed. The blank can be filled in by $x$, the other by $y$. I leave it to you to determine which.

Comment: I added my real problem to my question, which is much more complicated. I'm afraid your current solution will not work.

Comment: I have added to my answer. Take a look and see if it helps you in your bigger question. DeMorgan's laws and distributivity are good things to keep in mind, as are the facts that $p\wedge T=p\vee F=p.$

Comment: It's great! This is exactly what I want! The result you simplified is simpler than mine. It proves that my "action e" will never be executed. It is of great help to me.

Comment: Nice job, Cameron. +1

Comment: Thanks, @Rick. (I +1'd yours, too, for its fantastic clarity.)

Answer (score 2):

This is quite similar to Cameron's answer, worded a bit differently. If $x\land y$ is false, then by DeMorgan, either $x$ is false or $y$ is false.

**Case 1** ($x\equiv F$). In this case $(x\land \neg y)$ is false, so $(x\land \neg y)\equiv F\equiv\ ?$.

**Case 2** ($y\equiv F)$. In this case $(x\land \neg y)\equiv x\land T\equiv\ ?$

You should be able to fill in the question marks now.

Answer (score 1):

I find a solution to solve my first set of problem, that is to use the substitution method.

Simplify $x \wedge \lnot y$:
$$\begin{align}
  & x \wedge \lnot y \\
= & x \wedge \lnot y \vee \mathbf{F} \\
= & x \wedge \lnot y \vee x \wedge y \\
= & x 
\end{align}$$

Simplify `!b && c || a && c`, get `(! a && b) || c`. It seemingly isn't  much simplified.

Simplify `a && !c || !b && !c`, get 'True'.

For the second question, I transform $\lnot(x \wedge y)\rightarrow \left [ (x \wedge \lnot y) \Leftrightarrow z \right ]$ to conjunctive normal form $(\lnot x \vee y \vee z) \wedge (x \vee \lnot z)$.

We know to make $(\lnot x \vee y \vee z) \wedge (x \vee \lnot z)$ a tautology, $(\lnot x \vee y \vee z)$ and $(x \vee \lnot z)$ should be tautology first.

From the first part, z could be x or $\lnot y$; from the second part, z could be x. As a result, the only solution is z=x.